# Exception handling with SqsTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs

I have a Spring Boot app v3.2.1, and I'm using `spring-cloud-aws-starter-sqs` v3.1.0.

I saw this example for sending a message to the queue, but it doesn't address error handling at all:

```
sqsTemplate
    .send(sqsSendOptions ->
        sqsSendOptions
            .queue("myqueue")
            .payload(message)
    );
```

How do you handle errors if sending a message to the queue fails?

Thanks.